# El ancho del encabezado de la tabla DataTables no está alineado porque la tabla está oculta en una pestaña

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Ya probé con .columns.adjust (); con width = "100%" y de ninguna de las 2 formas funciona, pero cuando hago clic para ordenar la tabla o abrir el inspector de Google, funciona. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme por favor? Lo agradecería

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var url = document.URL;
   id_hv = url.split("=");
   var table_mov = $('#tabla_movimientos').DataTable( {
       language: {
           "decimal": "",
           "emptyTable": "No hay información",
           "info": "Mostrando del _START_ al _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
           "infoEmpty": "Mostrando del 0 al 0 de 0 registros",
           "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total registros)",
           "infoPostFix": "",
           "thousands": ",",
           "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
           "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
           "processing": "Procesando...",
           "search": "Buscar:",
           "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
           "paginate": {
               "first": "Primero",
               "last": "Ultimo",
               "next": "Siguiente",
               "previous": "Anterior"
           }
       },
       scrollY:        '30vh',
       scrollCollapse: true,
       paging:         true,
       "ajax": 'mostrar_tabla.php?tabla=movimientos&id_hv='+id_hv[1]+'',
       "columns": [     // <-- Columnas como se encuentran la base de datos
       { data: 'id_mov'  },
       { data: 'id_hv'  },
       { data: 'fecha_mov' },
       { data: 'sede_anterior' },
       { data: 'sede_actual'  },
       { data: 'nombre'  }

       ],

       orderCellsTop: true,
       fixedHeader: true
   });
});
```

Esta es la parte donde escondo la tabla y muestro el contenido de la pestaña

```
function equipo(evt, modulo)
{
   var head;
   head = document.getElementsByClassName("head");

   if (modulo == 'datos')
   {
       head[0].style.display = 'block';
   }else{
       head[0].style.display = 'none';
   }
   var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
   tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
   for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++)
   {
       tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
   }
   tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
   for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++)
   {
       tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
   }
   document.getElementById(modulo).style.display = "block";
   evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

y esta es mi tabla dentro del contenido de la pestaña oculta

```
<div id="movimientos" class="tabcontent">
            <h3>Movimientos</h3>
            <div class="contenedor">
                <section class="tabla">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="tabla_movimientos" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-sm" style="width:100%" >
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID MOV</th>
                                    <th>ID HV</th>
                                    <th>FECHA MOV</th>
                                    <th>SEDE ANT</th>
                                    <th>SEDE ACT</th>
                                    <th>USUARIO</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
```

También utilicé autoWidth, column-sizing y no funciona. He leído en diferentes plataformas y dice que es por tener la tabla oculta dentro de un tab (pestaña), pero sigo sin encontrar una solución para mi problema

[image: inicialmente el tab que esta activo es el de datos, luego cuando cambio a documentos (que es donde está la tabla), es donde ocurre el problema con el tamaño de la cabecera de la tabla... cuando ordeno la tabla se organiza]

Comment: No comprendo bien el problema, podrías hacer un [mcve] ?

Comment: Adjunte una imagen donde se puede ver el error...inicialmente el tab que se encuentra activo es el de datos del equipo, cuando muestro el tab de documentos (donde esta la tabla) ocurre el problema. Cuando ordeno la tabla o abro el inspector de Google funciona correctamente. @Nicolas Oñate

Comment: ¿Te fijaste en [`responsive.recalc()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc())?

Comment: @padaleiana no utilice ese exactamente pero con el enlace que me dejaste en el comentario encontré la solución. Muchas gracias a ambos por su ayuda.

Comment: En ese caso, explica la solución que encontraste, como respuesta :)

Comment: Use .columns.adjust() nuevamente pero esta vez acompañado de ` if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#example' ) ) ` donde oculto la tabla antes de mostrarla. Así quedó mi código `if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#tabla_documentos' ) )
 {
     table_doc = $('#tabla_documentos').DataTable();
     table_doc.columns.adjust();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código completo con la solución...Le añadí los 2 últimos if

```
function equipo(evt, modulo)
{
    var head;
    head = document.getElementsByClassName("head");

    if (modulo == 'datos')
    {
        head[0].style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        head[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++)
    {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++)
    {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(modulo).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

    if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#tabla_documentos' ) )
    {
        table_doc = $('#tabla_documentos').DataTable();
        table_doc.columns.adjust();
    }
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#tabla_movimientos' ) )
    {
        table_mov = $('#tabla_movimientos').DataTable();
        table_mov.columns.adjust();
    }

}
```